# Default TextBlock style overriding button text color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, textblock

My problem occurs with WPF in .NET 3.5 SP1 and can be described as follows:

I have a default `Style` hitting all `TextBlock` elements in my UI. That is how it looks:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

That works fine for all `TextBlock`s. In addition to that I have a `Button` style including a `ControlTemplate` that looks like this (shortened):

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="Border" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                    Height="24" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                 TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>...</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Notice the line `TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"` in the `ContentPresenter`. This should set the button text to green and in fact it does in the designer view of Visual Studio. But when I compile and run the program the button text is red, the text color is set by the default `TextBlock` style. I verified this with Snoop.

How can I prevent the default`TextBlock` style from overriding the `TextBlock.Foreground` value? The `OverridesDefaultStyle` property of `ContentPresenter` doesn't help in this case.

Any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See answer 5 at [this link](http://www.go4answers.com/Example/textbloxk-style-override-label-style-73551.aspx)

> This happends because the
> ContentPresenter creates a TextBlock
> for a string content, and since that
> TextBlock isn't in the visual tree, it
> will lookup to Application level
> resource. And if you define a style
> for the TextBlock at Application
> level, then it will be applied to
> these TextBlock within ContentControl
>
> A workaround is to define a
> DataTemplate for System.String, where
> we can explicitly use a default
> TextBlock to display the content. You
> can place that DataTemplate in the
> same dictionary you define the
> TextBlock style so that this
> DataTemplate will be applied  to
> whatever ContentPresenter effected by
> your style.

Try adding this to the ResourceDictionary

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock.Resources> 
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"/>
        </TextBlock.Resources>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's two things I don't understand: 1. Even if the TextBlock created by the ContentPresenter is not in the VisualTree it should still accept the values I put in TextBlock.Foreground, right? 2. By using the DataTemplate you described I am restricted to only one style for all texts inside ContentPresenter elements, correct?

Comment: @HA: As I understand it, it will only make sure the other TextBlock Style isn't picket up. But I could be wrong, I've used it before and I haven't had any problems with it

Comment: @HA: Also, this will only be used when a TextBlock is created because of the Content of a ContentControl. You can still do the things you do in your example, like setting the Foreground etc. Or am I missunderstanding the question?

Comment: No, you're right. I didn't fully understand it at first. However I decided not to use this solution, because it fails if I put an Image or Rectangle or something else inside the button. Instead I removed the Foreground property from the default TextBlock style. That way works better for me. Nonetheless thank you for your help.

Comment: OVERRIDING DATA TEMPLATE FOR System.String IS A BAD IDEA, because it loses underscore-to-keyboard-shortcut and ContentStringFormat functionality. This put me in hot water. See more details here: http://www.ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/wpftextstyle/StringTemplate.shtml

Comment: You can use `AccessText` instead of `TextBlock` to preserve keyboard shortcut functionality.

Answer (score 6):

You are better off not overriding default style for the TextBlock. The best idea I could come up with so far is to create a style for Control and apply it to all top level windows.

```
<!-- App.xaml -->
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RedStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>

<!-- MainWindow.xaml -->
<Window Style="{StaticResource RedStyle}" ...>
    ...
</Window>
```

See here for more details: http://www.ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/wpftextstyle/

Answer (score 2):

With respect to the 2 options:

1. @Fredrik Hedblad

> Try adding this to the ResourceDictionary

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock.Resources> 
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"/>
        </TextBlock.Resources>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

2. @Ivan Krivyakov

> You are better off not overriding default style for the TextBlock. The best idea I could come up with so far is to create a style for Control and apply it to all top level windows.

**I would suggest an alternative approach and use an attached Dependency Property e.g.**

```
namespace AttachedProperties
{
  public static class TextBlockExtensions
  {
    public static bool GetUseAppThemeStyle(DependencyObject obj)
    {
      return (bool)obj.GetValue(UseAppThemeStyleProperty);
    }
    public static void SetUseAppThemeStyle(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
      obj.SetValue(UseAppThemeStyleProperty, value);
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UseAppThemeStyle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UseAppThemeStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UseAppThemeStyle", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBlockExtensions), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
  }
}
```

> NOTE: You can set it to be true or false by default

Then having the namespace:

```
xmlns:attachedProperties="clr-namespace:AttachedProperties"
```

make a default style:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(attachedProperties:TextBlockExtensions.UseAppThemeStyle), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Then if you need to get the default you can just set the attached property either in a style:

```
  <Style x:Key="blueButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="attachedProperties:TextBlockExtensions.UseAppThemeStyle" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
  </Style>
```

or directly on a button:

```
<Button attachedProperties:TextBlockExtensions.UseAppThemeStyle="False" Foreground="Blue">I'm blue da ba dee da ba die...</Button>
```