# WPF Style Foreground of RadioButton not applied

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have a style for my textblocks, and a style for my radio button.

When I add my radio buttons, they ignore the style for my foreground. The textblock style seems to have precedence and I can't get it the way I want it.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Daytona Light"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Radio" TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#1a3281"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Border  
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1a3281" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I create my radio buttons in a stack panel

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource Radio}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50, 0, 0, 20"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            
            <RadioButton GroupName="MainSelection" Command="{Binding ShowVideoCommand}" Content="Video">
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton GroupName="MainSelection" Command="{Binding ShowPresentationCommand}" Content="Presentation">
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton GroupName="MainSelection" Command="{Binding ShowSimulatorCommand}" Content="Simulator">
            </RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
```

When I run my app, I see the radio buttons as full white rectangles. When the RadioButton is checked, the style for the background works fine (becomes blue, with text still white).

What am I doing wrong for my foreground style? Why is the textblock style always wins over my radio button style?

Even when I set Foreground="Red" in my RadioButton as follows

```
<RadioButton Foreground="Red" GroupName="MainSelection" Command="{Binding ShowVideoCommand}" Content="Video">
```

it won't show up. Text is always white.

Comment: I just ran your code and I see blueish foreground for radio buttons and cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Pff.. found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500115/default-textblock-style-overriding-button-text-color. Solved the problem. Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: That would mean the code you showed is not your real code...

Comment: But it is. Of course not all of it. But nothing else interacts with textblock in a radio button